# How do I stop VS2017 from auto-replacing _inline_ tabs with spaces?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tabs, inline, autoformatting

I have Visual Studio 2017 for C# (Express and Community) and I am trying to add some inline comments to my class attributes for Doxygen. Between my declaration and my comment I wish to have tabs to align my comments properly. VS however replaces those tabs with spaces every time I hit the autoformat keys Ctrl-K Ctrl-D. It doesn't help to set "Keep tabs" under "Tools/Options/Text Editor/C#/Tabs". VS doesn't keep those tabs anyway. I didn't find anything under "C#/Code Style/Formatting" either.

Is there anyway to prevent autoformat from replacing my tabs?

I already tried asking on MSDN, but everything they told my to try out didn't help, see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e92eb5fd-c00e-4331-9814-b69b81ade3ac/autoformat-replaces-tabs-with-spaces?forum=csharpgeneral).